# повторная выборка записей из MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Возможно ли средствами SQL сделать выборку из выборки? 
Например, выборка всех сообщений из БД :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id'";
$result= mysql_query($query);
```

Теперь в $resoure - все сообщения. Выводим на экран их количество.
Теперь необходимо выбрать записи с отпределенным значением поля 'is_read' . Можно ли как-то использовать предыдущий результат или придется делать еще одну выборку(по тем же данным!!) :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id' AND is_read='not_read'"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почему нельзя, допустим, сначала выбирать подсчет по тому запросу

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM table WHERE id='$id'";
$result= mysql_query($query);
```

выводить `total`, а вот потом уже выборку делать по интересующим вас критериям?

Comment: Так я все-таки и поступил.

Answer (score 1):

Можно же с массивами работать, например вы вытащили все из БД:

```
$result= mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($query));
// Далее если вам где нужно вытащить из этого массива то можно это так
$a = array_filter($result,function ($v) {return $v['is_read'] == "not_read";})
print_r($a);
```

Это вам даст все массивы где is_read='not_read' и не надо все время делать запрос. Во общем примерно так должен быть

Comment: Очень хороший вариант для небольших объемов данных. Но вытаскивать из БД вашим кодом можно только первую запись. Таким образом о массивах не может быть и речи.

Comment: Ах да, вы правы, это даст только первый элемент, но с помощью циклов можно получить все массивы какие нам нужны, например так:

// Для цикла нужен ключ например $result[$i]["not_read"];
for($i = 1;$i < count($result)+1;$i++){
$res[$i] = array_values(array_filter($result,function ($v) {return $v['is_read'] == $result[$i]["not_read"];}));

}
// если сделать print_r($res) то увидим лишные ключи нп: array([0]=>[0]=>[is_read],[1]=>[1]=>[is_read])
// для этого удаляем первые ключи 
foreach($res as $k=>$v)$res[$k]=$v[0];

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно попробовать средствами MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM  
    (SELECT COUNT(table.id) FROM table WHERE table.id='$id') As countId, 
    (SELECT table.* FROM table WHERE table.id='$id') As tmpTabel  
WHERE tmpTabel.is_read='not_read'
```

В результате получим таблицу с выборкой `is_read='not_read'` и дополнительным значением в каждой строке `countId`